# Can we consider that the photons that were not and will never be detected live in a zero-dimensional space?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, photons, time, observers

According to Einstein’s theory of relativity, any particle traveling at the speed of light experiences no passage of time. It follows that if a photon travels through space then within any two points of its trajectory the proper elapse of time for the photon is zero, which means that the photon is in all the points of its trajectory at the same proper time, and therefore that from the photon’s perspective every two points of its trajectory are at a distance zero from each other (since it takes zero time to go from one to the other, or simply because the photon -a wave- occupies all of the space simultaneously).

If this speculation is somehow correct, does it mean that all the photons emitted since the Big Bang that never will be detected inhabit a zero-dimensional space? (a metric space where the distance between any two points is zero is necessarily a point), and if the answer is “yes”, can we think of this space as a a singularity with an infinite energy density?

Comment: If you were a photon, then you would only lose the ability to use your proper time as one of your coordinates.

Comment: What would this be useful for? Does it make you just go "woah cool", or is this somehow useful for calculating the outcome of an experiment.

Comment: I don't think so, but it might be related to Penrose's cyclic cosmology? As for the comment before, the zero-dimensionality would apply to the time coordinate as well I suppose?

Comment: @AXensen Not everyone just shuts up and calculate, most physicists are also interested in philosophical issues, such as how to interpret a theory.

Comment: @David There is no zero dimensionality here. Metric doesn't affect dimension.

Comment: Photons are the amounts of energy that gets transferred from the free field to matter during an absorption process. They don't "exist" independently of the absorption/detection process. You are using words from physics that are often misunderstood in a way that simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: @FlatterMann Isn't legitimate to think of undetected photons as waves travelling through space at the speed of light? As far as I believe to understand, photons do not exist as particles before being detected, but they exist as waves.

Comment: No, it isn't. Nobody has ever detected a free photon and the structure of quantum mechanics does not claim that they exist.

Comment: @FlatterMann Could you please elaborate/give a link explaining why it isn’t?  I mean what paradoxes/contradictions follow from this interpretation? I more or less understand that photons can be interpreted as disturbances of an existing field, but why can’t them be described as a time-dependent potential disturbance of the field before being detected, i.e., a real property of the real field? I hope I’m not asking pure nonsense. In any case, what does the wave function of an undetected emitted photon would correspond to if it’s not describing an existing entity/property of the universe?

Comment: Photons are small amounts of energy. They are the amounts of energy that get emitted from a source or that get absorbed by an absorber or detector. They are not properties of the fields and they are certainly not disturbances of the field. The classical fields are the averages of many photon emissions and absorptions. A wave function doesn't describe one photon. It describes the unmeasured quantum mechanical ensemble (i.e. an infinite number of identical but completely independent copies of the system). I know that this is hard to grasp intuitively for now. It's not intuitive.

Comment: @FlatterMann Ok, I certainly don't want to make the thread too long, but why is the emission-without-absorption of a photon impossible? And if it isn't, why is the ontological nature of an emitted-but-not absorbed photon equivalent to its nonexistence. In other words, is there a difference between a photon that was emitted but not absorbed and no photon at all?, and if there's no difference, how can a photon be emitted without "knowing in advance" that it will be absorbed? And if it has to "know in advance", would  this mean that information can travel from future to past?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150975/discussion-between-flattermann-and-david).

Comment: @PatoGalmarini I'm not saying everyone needs to be doing calculations on pen and paper all day. Einstein used a 4d manifold as a model for spacetime. This mathematical model exists, and is useful and valid, because it can be used to make predictions. If you say "photons inhabit a zero-dimensional space," it isn't meaningful unless this "zero-dimensional space" is a mathematical object that is part of a model for describing the outcome of some experiment. If your statements absolutely fundamentally have no connection to any possible experiment, it isn't physics. its nonsense phraseology.

Answer (score 3):

The spacetime of special relativity is a 4-dimensional affine space.  On this affine space, a Minkowski pseudo-metric is given. For timelike intervals, this metric gives the proper time elapsed for the observer moving along the line of this interval. For lightlike intervals, it gives $0$. This doesn't affect the dimension of anything. It does not even mean that you cannot use a lightlike coordinate line. It means only that you cannot parametrize this coordinate line with its pseudo-length. In more physicist terms, if there are two events (=points) on a lightlike world-line, then their pseudo-distance is $0$, but this does not mean that these two events are the same.

Comment: The events (points) are not the same from the perspective of an observer outside a lightlike interval, but how can them be distinguished from the perspective of a (seemingly impossible?) observer in the lightlike interval? In other words: if the Minkowsky space can be embedded in a higher dimensional Euclidean space E (I don't know if it can), wouldn't the lightlike intervals collapse into a space-time point in E? Also: isn't the characterization of Minkowsky´s distance as a pseudo-metric valid only from the perspective of an observer travelling slower than the speed of light?

Comment: No. Minkowski spacetime is independent of any observer. An observer performs only a special coordinatization of spacetime $M$, i.e. he defines $\mathbb R^4\to M$ mapping. Real (timelike) observers can use the space coordinates plus the time, but a hypothetical lightlike observer can't.  However, the observer is not obliged to use space and time coordinates. For example, you can use affine coordinates determined by a (not orthonormal) basis consisting of 4 linearly independent lightlike vectors. Such a basis is called a *null basis*, because it consists of vectors of $0$ pseudo-length.

Comment: If the coordinate vectors have zero pseudo-length, wouldn't every point in this coordinate system be located at the (pseudo-)origin? In other words,  how could a lightlike observer distinguish any two distinct events? (from the perspective of a time-like observer)

Comment: She can't. Still, those events are different because real observers can distinguish them.  An observer is only a viewpoint of the world. For example, if you look at a page of a book from its edge, you can't say what is written on that page, still there is something written.

Comment: I guess my question can be asked also as follows: if there were nothing but electromagnetic waves in the universe (its observers are also made of them), would the observers inside this universe have any experience of space or time? The question has to do with the space-time topology of the universe as seen from the perspective of the photons, not from that of real observers (by which I understand observers capable of experiencing time). My motivation for this question comes from the ideas of cyclic cosmology, but it looks to me independent from them.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. Of course, they must have some feeling of the real structure. Imagine two lightlike world lines, $a$ and $b$  crossing the same third light-like world-line $c$. The event of the two crossings will be the same for $c$ but not for $a$ nor $b$, since they don't meet